# Scatter plot is not getting published in streamlit

Tags: python, scatter-plot, streamlit

This below code for streamlit Python program is working fine.

```
avg=s/c
k=s2.std(axis=1)
cv=(k/avg) 
b6=b9.assign(average_value=avg,Std_Dev=k,Coff_Var=cv)
b8=b6.loc[b6['average_value'] > 1]
st.write(b8)
```

However , I wanted to plot a scatter plot chart of the variables and wrote the following lines

```
graph=pd.DataFrame(b6,columns=['Std_Dev','Coff_Var'])        <------------This is line 61
plt.scatter(graph['Std_Dev'],graph['Coff_Var'])
st.pyplot()
```

I am not getting the results and its resulting in following error.

TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
File "C:\Users\bahlrajesh23\datascience\data_charts.py", line 61, in 
graph=pd.DataFrame(b6,columns=['Std_Dev','Coff_Var'])

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure what your variable `b6` is, but it *seems* to be a string type and holds this path to a file: `"C:\Users\bahlrajesh23\datascience\data_charts.py"`, not a tuple of data points.

If you're trying to create a pandas data frame from a file you need to pass in data or use `pd.read_` and then the file type usually (csv is `pd.read_csv`, excel is `pd.read_excel`, etc... ). Then you can pass this a path to the file you want to use:

```
data = pd.read_csv("path/to/file/data.csv")
```

Not sure what plotting package your using? `plt` could refer to matplotlib, altair, etc.. but I would generally recommend making a figure and axes handles that you can use to write to the screen (this is a matplotlib example):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

plt.scatter(data)

st.write(fig)
```